# Trying to identify DC connector (5.5 mm OD, 3.0 mm ID, no pin)

Tags: identification, standard, power-connector

I need to replace a DC adapter for an old NAS that was lost to a power spike but I'm having a hard time identifying exactly the kind of connector.

This is the connector on the back of the NAS:

[image]

I have this universal adapter kit that I use temporarily:

[image: DC adapter kit with multiple plugs]

And after testing a few plugs I discovered this is the one I need:

[image]

The plug has the following specifications:

- outer diameter: **5.5 mm**
- inner diameter: **3.0 mm**
- **no pin** inside the plug (the pin is in the NAS connector)

I don't want to keep using the kit and need to find a definitive replacement. However, I'm having a hard time finding one with these exact specs.

I would like to know:

- Is this a standard size?
- Is there an IEC-like code for it?

Any additional information is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right ID? 5.5mm OD with 2.5mm ID is a standard barrel plug size. I'd suggest you buy one of those and try it to see if it fits.

Comment: What's stopping you from looking at the connector on the original power supply, or using it with another power supply?

Comment: This is a standard barrel plug. They come in several sizes, though an ID of 3 mm is unusual.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the original connector?

Comment: @Justme the original connector melted due to the power supply failure but I'm sure it had these same specs because the plug from the kit fitted perfectly.

Comment: @user324996 I tried the 5.5mm OD x 2.5mm ID plug from the universal adapter kit but it didn't fit.

What's baffling me is that the kit has this 5.5x3.0 plug that fits perfectly but I'm not able to find it anywhere else...

Comment: I need an adapter for that size, 3mm ID, 5.5mm OD but can’t find one anywhere. Can you tell where you got that adapter kit please?

Comment: yeah there are oddball sizes out there. barrel jacks lack a commonly used standard, afaik. especially when it comes to the variations on length of inside/outside/pin. Manufacturers sometimes specifically motivated by *incompatibility*, to avoid alien plugs

Comment: @PedroAlmeida You have a power adaptor. It works. You want to buy another power adaptor. Why not leave the one that's working alone and just buy another universal one like the one you have (which is probably about the same price as the custom one your looking for).

Answer (score 5):

You can search for DC power connectors at [Mouser](https://eu.mouser.com/c/connectors/power-connectors/dc-power-connectors/) and [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-connectors/435) and others and do a parametric search (or set a filter) on inner/outer size, gender, etc. to find the right size and type. Note that different lengths are sometimes also available.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but alas I was not able to find this specific adapter. I'll keep using the plug from the universal adapter but this "investigation" has become a minor obsession of mine, any additional information or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It certainly is an odd one at that size. I did find this one link...
https://www.elliottelectronicsupply.com/3-0mm-x-5-5mm-dc-coaxial-plug.html

Answer (score 0):

This is old post, but out of curiosity I found the adapter that matches the original picture: it is [Fonte Carregador Universal para Notebook 90W Elgin - com 9 pontas Intercambiáveis - 46RFTE90W000](https://www.oficinadosbits.com.br/produto/fonte-carregador-universal-para-notebook-90w-elgin-com-8-pontas-intercambiaveis-46rfte90w000/)

The listing has list of tip sizes, and the white one is described as:

> `5.5*3.0*12`  Acer /AMS Tech / Asus / BenQ / Compaq / Dell / Fujitsu / Hasee / Gateway / Hitachi / HP / IBM / Lenovo / LG / NEC / Panasonic / Sharp / Toshiba

Sadly, this does not seem to be a standard size - searching for this connector size usually yields the model with pin inside. Perhaps one can take 5.0 x 2.5mm connector (very common) and grind out inner diameter?